# If one fraction has a smaller numerator and a larger denominator than another, will it always be the smaller fraction (and vice-versa)?

Tags: fractions

E.g. take:

> a/b and c/d

If

> c < a and d > b

Will

> c/d < a/b

?

Comment: Assume that $a,b,c,d > 0$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA - it is enough to assume $b,d>0$

Comment: $\dfrac c d < \dfrac a b \text { iff } (\dfrac c d)b < (\dfrac a b)b \text { iff } d(\dfrac c d)b < d(\dfrac a b)b$.

Comment: From this, you cannot conclude that $c < a \text { and } b < d$. We may have $a=b=d=2$ and $c=1$ i.e. $\dfrac c d = \dfrac 1 2 < \dfrac 2 2 = \dfrac a b$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA not quite : beware of the sign!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a,b,c,d$ are all positive, this holds.

But beware if some of them are negative! eg take a=-1, b = -1, c=-5, d=-0.5
one has $a > c$ and $d>b$, yet $\frac{c}{d} = 10 > 1 = \frac{a}{b}$.

**edit (building on Henry's remark above)**
It is indeed enough that $b>0$ and $d>0$ :
Since $b>0$ one has $\frac{a}{b} > \frac{c}{d} \Longleftrightarrow a > \frac{bc}{d}$.
But since $d>0$ one has $a >  \frac{bc}{d} \Longleftrightarrow ad > bc$. Now, as $d>b$ and $a>c>0$, you get $ad>bc$ whence the claim.